# Is Mr. Snookums a reference to Dogpool?

Tags: deadpool

In the High Moon Studios game *Deadpool*, there is a dog shown to belong to Wade Wilson that he has named Mr. Snookums. He appears to be a normal dog at first, but later survives an explosion from a grenade blast after the Blockbuster/Rogue fight. This makes it appear that he would have healing capabilities, much like Dogpool, a member of the Deadpool Corps.

If anyone can tell me whether or not this is coincidence or not, it would be greatly appreciated.